# Reload code for AAPL wordpress plugin (javascripts that writes on the DOM)

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, reload

I'm having some troubles with AAPL for Wordpress and its reload codes.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/

I have to reload a Flickr widget that calls a Javascript from the Flickr widget URLs. It calls this URL like a JS:

http://www.flickr.com/badge_code_v2.gne?count=9&display=random&&layout=x&source=user&user=(USERID)@N02&size=s

The javascript called returns this markup:

```
var b_txt = '';

// write the badge



    b_txt+= '<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image1"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/92475511@N02/8405790393/"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8375/8405790393_ef9e7a4e55_s.jpg" alt="Una foto su Flickr" title="9° Palio delle Facoltà @ CUS Catania" height="75" width="75"></a></div>';


    b_txt+= '<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image2"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/92475511@N02/8406884700/"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8358/8406884700_812180d298_s.jpg" alt="Una foto su Flickr" title="Mercatini di Natale - Dicembre 2012" height="75" width="75"></a></div>';


    b_txt+= '<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image3"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/92475511@N02/8406883634/"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8370/8406883634_cdb4b75b27_s.jpg" alt="Una foto su Flickr" title="Sit in di protesta contro la Strage di Brindisi" height="75" width="75"></a></div>';


    b_txt+= '<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image4"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/92475511@N02/8405790285/"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8405790285_4c6f762a9e_s.jpg" alt="Una foto su Flickr" title="9° Palio delle Facoltà @ CUS Catania" height="75" width="75"></a></div>';


    b_txt+= '<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image5"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/92475511@N02/8406892022/"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8213/8406892022_027ae8b541_s.jpg" alt="Una foto su Flickr" title="Samuela Schilirò @ Feltrinelli - Catania" height="75" width="75"></a></div>';


    b_txt+= '<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image6"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/92475511@N02/8406884602/"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8183/8406884602_8aa7d0046a_s.jpg" alt="Una foto su Flickr" title="Sit in di protesta contro la Strage di Brindisi" height="75" width="75"></a></div>';


    b_txt+= '<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image7"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/92475511@N02/8405790967/"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8237/8405790967_b2926b1218_s.jpg" alt="Una foto su Flickr" title="9° Palio delle Facoltà @ CUS Catania" height="75" width="75"></a></div>';


    b_txt+= '<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image8"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/92475511@N02/8405791329/"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8216/8405791329_398c6b0d4e_s.jpg" alt="Una foto su Flickr" title="Mercatini di Natale - Dicembre 2012" height="75" width="75"></a></div>';


    b_txt+= '<div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image9"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/92475511@N02/8406884314/"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8497/8406884314_92e5c6dc61_s.jpg" alt="Una foto su Flickr" title="Sit in di protesta contro la Strage di Brindisi" height="75" width="75"></a></div>';


b_txt += '<span style="position:absolute;left:-999em;top:-999em;visibility:hidden" class="flickr_badge_beacon"><img src="http://geo.yahoo.com/p?s=792600102&t=6e94e5b35e270281f978527bf40fa8db&r=http%3A%2F%2Fcatania.liveuniversity.it%2F&fl_ev=0&lang=it&intl=uk" width="0" height="0" alt="" /></span>';

document.write(b_txt);
```

So the Flickr JS writes directly the markup into the DOM.
Obviously it need to be reloaded by AAPL to re-execute the document.write.

Then i have to reload a JS file that has the same behaviour of the Flickr widget. I assume that both have to be reloaded in the same way:

```
    // Kirecom Networks
var images = [],
index = 0;

images[0] = "<a href = 'http://www.centrodidatticoathena.it/servizi' target='_blank'><img src='http://images.catania.liveuniversity.it/sites/3/athena/bannergenerale.jpg' width='262' alt='Athena'></a>";

images[1] = "<a href = 'http://www.centrodidatticoathena.it/corso-serale-di-inglese/' target='_blank'><img src='http://images.catania.liveuniversity.it/sites/3/athena/corsoinglese50.jpg' width='262' alt='Athena'></a>";

images[2] = "<a href = 'http://www.centrodidatticoathena.it/servizi/' target='_blank'><img src='http://images.catania.liveuniversity.it/sites/3/athena/tesi200.jpg' width='262' alt='Athena'></a>";

images[3] = "<a href = 'http://www.centrodidatticoathena.it/servizi/' target='_blank'><img src='http://images.catania.liveuniversity.it/sites/3/athena/lezionindividuali.jpg' width='262' alt='Athena'></a>";

images[4] = "<a href = 'http://www.centrodidatticoathena.it/servizi/' target='_blank'><img src='http://images.catania.liveuniversity.it/sites/3/athena/inglesespagnolo5.jpg' width='262' alt='Athena'></a>";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

document.write(images[index]);

//Stop randomizing
```

Can you please help me with the reload code? In my thought i should re-write the JS files into the div, selecting it with his ID, or refresh the DIV that contains the javascripts (they're into the body of the page) but i don't know how to do that.

Many Thanks!